# trying to execute if-else-if loop in batch programming

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, spritebatch

I am trying to execute if-else loop in batch programming, but it is giving me unexpected output

code:

```
echo 1. ICM
echo 2. Mini ICM
echo 3. SST
set /p ch = Enter the number(1 or 2 or 3) for Type of Environment :
echo.

IF "%ch%" EQU "1" ( 
set str1="ATTST"
) ELSE ( 
IF "%ch%" EQU "2" ( 
set str1="NBIST" 
) ELSE ( 
IF "%ch%" EQU "3" ( 
set str1="NBISST" 
) ELSE (
echo "Incorrect choice" 
    )))

echo "######################"



echo "Value of str1 is :"
echo "%str1%"

pause
```

Output I am getting is :

```
1. ICM
2. Mini ICM
3. SST
Enter the number(1 or 2 or 3) for

"Incorrect choice"
"######################"
"Value of str1 is :"
""
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can anyone help me, where I am wrong?

Comment: remove the space after "ch" here: `set /p ch=Enter`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach:

```
:again
set /p "ch=Enter the number(1 or 2 or 3) for Type of Environment : "
set "str1="
IF "%ch%" EQU "1" set str1="ATTST"
IF "%ch%" EQU "2" set str1="NBIST" 
IF "%ch%" EQU "3" set str1="NBISST" 
if not defined str1 echo "Incorrect choice" & goto :again
echo value is %str1%
```

also, you should have a look at `choice /?`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space:

```
set /p ch = Enter the number(1 or 2 or 3) for Type of Environment :
         ^
```

Silly as it is, cmd will create an env var named `ch[space]`:

```
C:\Users\marc>set /p ch = foo
foobar

C:\Users\marc>echo %ch%
%ch%

C:\Users\marc>echo %ch %
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Command line will create a variable called "ch " because you have space.

You should use `"set /p ch=Enter the number(1 or 2 or 3) for Type of Environment :"`

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the [array approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), that is much simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the list of "option=type" pairs
rem and create "option" and "type" arrays with it
set i=0
for %%a in ("ICM=ATTST" "Mini ICM=NBIST" "SST=NBISST") do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set /A i+=1
      set "option[!i!]=%%b"
      set "type[!i!]=%%c"
   )
)

rem Show the menu
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
   echo %%i. !option[%%i]!
)

:getOption
set /p ch=Enter the number (from 1 to %i%) for Type of Environment :
echo/

if defined option[%ch%] (
   set str1="!type[%ch%]!"
) ELSE (
   echo "Incorrect choice" 
   goto getOption
)

echo "######################"

echo "Value of str1 is :"
echo "%str1%"

pause
```